# Jquery: how does one get a .play() function to execute during an if else statement?

Tags: jquery, html, css

`"message": "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).play is not a function"`

This is the error I am recieving. . . Basically I need this function to hide some divs and show and play a video. My code does not work at this moment with the error above.

Jquery in question is commented out.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
     containment: 'body', 
        revert:  function(dropped) {
             var $draggable = $(this),
                 hasBeenDroppedBefore = $draggable.data('hasBeenDropped'),
                 wasJustDropped = dropped && dropped[0].id == "droppable";
             if(wasJustDropped) {
                 return true;
             } else {
                 if (hasBeenDroppedBefore) {
                     $draggable.animate({ top: 0, left: 0 }, 'slow');
                     return false;
                 } else {
                     return true;
                 }
             }
        }
    });
    
   $("#droppable").droppable({
       over: function() {
           $(this).find('p').html('Reading...');
       },

       out: function() {
           var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
// The  $('#secondVideo').play(); is not causing my video to play after it shows
           if (number == 1) {
               $('#draggable, #draggable2, #droppable, #upperSwiper, #swiper, #firstVideo').hide();
               $('#secondVideo').show();
               $('#secondVideo').play();
           } else {
               $(this).find('p').html('Please Swipe Again At This Website To Enter');
           }
       },

       revert: function() {
           $(this).find('p').html('');
       },

       drop: function() {
           $(this).find('p').html('Error Reading Your Card');

       }
   });   
});
```

```css
html, body {
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  height:100%;
  body:100%;
}

#reader {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #696969;
 width: 40%;
 height: 75px;
    Top: 89%;
    left:30%;
    z-index: 4;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
 }

div.frontReader {
 background-color: #a9a9a9;
 width: 95%;
 height: 65px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
 z-index: ;
 left: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 }

#firstVideo {
 position: absolute;
 width: 93%;
 height: auto;
 z-index: -2;
 margin-left: auto; 
   margin-right: auto;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
 } 
 
#secondVideo {
 position: absolute;
 width: 93%;
 height: auto;
 z-index: 3;
 margin-left: auto; 
   margin-right: auto;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   display:none;
 }

div.blackBar {
 position: relative;
 background-color: black;
 width: 250px;
 height: 23px;
 top: 75%;
 }

div.frontSwiper {
 background-color: #A9A9A9;
 width: 85%;
 height: 70px;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
 clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
 z-index: ;
 border-radius: 10px;
 }
 
body { 
 background-color: black;
 width: 100%; 
 height: 100%;
 margin: auto; 
 }
 
#swiper {
 background-color: #b8b8b8;
 width: 100%;
 height: 70px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative; 
    Top: 91%;
    z-index: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
 }
 
#upperSwiper {
 background-color: transparent;
 width: 34%;
 height: 75px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative; 
    Top: -90%;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 0px;
 }
 
#droppable { 
 width: 45%;
 Height: 63%;
    margin: 0 auto;
 border-Width: 1px;  
    background-image:none;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    top: 40%;
    
 }
 
#draggable, #draggable2 {
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 width: 250px; 
 height: 160px;  
 border-Width: 0px;
 background-image:none;
 left: 75%;
 background-color: #FFD700;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 91% 0, 100% 14%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
 clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 91% 0, 100% 14%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
 z-index; -1;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<video id="secondVideo" src="bRh-01.mp4">
 your browser does not support the video tag. 
</video>

<video id="firstVideo" loop autoplay src="bRh-03.mp4">
 your browser does not support the video tag. 
</video>

<div id="reader">
 <div class="frontReader"></div>
</div>
<div id="swiper">
 <div class="frontSwiper"></div>
 <div id="upperSwiper"></div>
</div>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
 <div class="blackBar"></div>
    <p></p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p style="font: italic bold 30px/40px Arial, Sans-serif; width: 75%, position: fixed; color: #FFD700;"></p>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the 'play' function is not a jQuery function but you're trying to use it on a jQuery object i.e. `$('#secondVideo').play();`.

You could either do this:

```
$('#secondVideo')[0].play();
```

Which will get the DOM element and then call `.play()` on it.

Or you could do this:

```
document.getElementById('secondVideo').play();
```

...which just uses vanilla javascript to get the element instead of jQuery.